# is it possibly to load data from DynamoDB directly from EMR pig?

Tags: apache-pig, amazon-dynamodb, emr

I know you can load data directly from DynamoDB in EMR hive, but what about EMR pig?

Is there a way to load data from DynamoDB dirctly in pig? Without first saving it to hdfs?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found out on the Amazon forums that this isn't supported. There were some plans to add this functionality at some point, but no ETA has ever been posted.